# Problem installing LVM2 under Raspbian 10

Tags: raspberry-pi, lvm

I am trying to install lvm2 on a Raspberry Pi, but apt install is crashing:

```
fruitloops% sudo apt install
[sudo] password for heller: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lvm2 (2.03.02-3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Failed to restart lvm2-lvmpolld.service: Unit lvm2-lvmpolld.socket is masked.
invoke-rc.d: initscript lvm2-lvmpolld, action "restart" failed.
● lvm2-lvmpolld.service - LVM2 poll daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lvm2-lvmpolld.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:lvmpolld(8)
dpkg: error processing package lvm2 (--configure):
 installed lvm2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lvm2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
fruitloops% cat /etc/is
issue      issue.net  
fruitloops% cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Right now, there are no LVM volumes, but the 32gig uSD is close to full and I want to install a larger uSD (I did this on a Banana Pi M64, retaining the original 32-gig partition as the "system disk" (mount point "/") and moved /home to a LVM volume.  I want to do the same on this Raspberry Pi.

Comment: have you tried unmasking `lvm2-lvmpolld.socket`?

Comment: One thing I can tell you, lvm2 installs without issue on 64 bit Bookworm - not sure about 32 bit, or the old Raspbian, which was never proper Debian in my opinion, and if you strayed too far from what the Raspberry Pi foundation numpties included in the base image, you always ended up with odd issues

Comment: lvm2 also installs without issue on another 32-bit arm Debian 10 system: a beaglebone.

Comment: OK, unmasking lvm2-lvmpolld.socket seems to have cured things.